# Find the range of the function $f(r) =$ $^{7-r}P_{r-3}$ where $^m P_n$ is the number of permutations of $n$ objects from $m$ objects

Tags: functions, problem-solving

> Find the range of the function $f(r) =$ $^{7-r}P_{r-3}$ where $^m P_n$ is the number of permutations of $n$ objects from $m$ objects (given that $r>0$) .

**What I Tried** :- I am really not that familiar with the definition of range of a function, but here's what I did :-

If $f(r) =$ $^{7-r}P_{r-3}$ , then  $(7 - r) > 0$ , $(r - 3) > 0$, since as far as I know $m!$ is not defined if $m < 0$.
This gives that $r < 7$, $r > 3$ . So $r$ is maximum $6$ and minimum $4$ in terms of integers.

I checked the definition of the range of a function, and it says that the range of a function is the set of all output values derived from that function.
So as far as my point of view, the answer is {$^3 P_1$ ,$^2 P_2$ ,}

Can someone confirm this for me? If not, can anyone show me how to do this problem?

Comment: This will be absolutely correct when you include $m \ge n$ constraint.

Comment: @cosmo5 I included $^1 P_3$ , when is $m  \geq n$ then?

Comment: How many permutations of choosing $3$ distinct items from $1$ item? Zero or meaningless?

Comment: @Henry I get it, it's not zero but rather meaningless. So I guess that's why $m \geq n$ ?

Comment: Yes, the *meaningless* interpretation corresponds to $m \ge n$. The *zero* interpretation does not have that condition

Comment: So is my answer correct now?